# Определить зацикливание массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть поток данных или массив с 100 000 000+ записей, значение указывает на ключ, как определить, что произошло зацикливание. В общем предложите свои решения. 
Я сделал так.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    var count = 100000000;
    var struct = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
        struct.push(temp);
    };
    struct.sort();


    $.each(struct, function(index, val) {
        if (struct[index] == struct[index-1]) {
            console.log('Произошло зацикливание');
            return false;
        }
    });


    console.log(struct);
});
```

Ещё пробовал деревом:

```
function BinarySearchTree() {
        this._root = null;
    }

    BinarySearchTree.prototype = {

        //restore constructor
        constructor: BinarySearchTree,

        add: function(value) {
            //create a new item object, place data in
            var node = {
                    value: value,
                    left: null,
                    right: null
                },

                //used to traverse the structure
                current;

            //special case: no items in the tree yet
            if (this._root === null) {
                this._root = node;
            } else {
                current = this._root;

                while (true) {

                    //if the new value is less than this node's value, go left
                    if (value < current.value) {

                        //if there's no left, then the new node belongs there
                        if (current.left === null) {
                            current.left = node;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            current = current.left;
                        }

                        //if the new value is greater than this node's value, go right
                    } else if (value > current.value) {

                        //if there's no right, then the new node belongs there
                        if (current.right === null) {
                            current.right = node;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            current = current.right;
                        }

                        //if the new value is equal to the current one, just ignore
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        contains: function(value) {
            var found = false,
                current = this._root

            //make sure there's a node to search
            while (!found && current) {

                //if the value is less than the current node's, go left
                if (value < current.value) {
                    current = current.left;

                    //if the value is greater than the current node's, go right
                } else if (value > current.value) {
                    current = current.right;

                    //values are equal, found it!
                } else {
                    found = true;
                }
            }

            //only proceed if the node was found
            return found;
        },

        remove: function(value) {},

        size: function() {
            var length = 0;

            this.traverse(function(node) {
                length++;
            });

            return length;
        },

        toArray: function() {
            var result = [];

            this.traverse(function(node) {
                result.push(node.value);
            });

            return result;
        },

        toString: function() {
            return this.toArray().toString();
        },

        traverse: function(process) {

            //helper function
            function inOrder(node) {
                if (node) {

                    //traverse the left subtree
                    if (node.left !== null) {
                        inOrder(node.left);
                    }

                    //call the process method on this node
                    process.call(this, node);

                    //traverse the right subtree
                    if (node.right !== null) {
                        inOrder(node.right);
                    }
                }
            }

            //start with the root
            inOrder(this._root);
        },

    };
```

Основываясь на одном и единственном из предложенных решений:
http://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/jWNXRz

Comment: чем ваш вопрос поможет будущим пользователям? кроме того: нет примера входных данных, нет определения _зацикливание_

Comment: Битовое поле, в котором отмечать уже посещенные элементы. Если текущий элемент уже был посещен - цикл. Делал такое на 4 лярда элементов.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, в яваскрипте есть битовые поля? :-)

Comment: @Grundy как один из вариантов очень большой змейки

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, честно говоря - понятнее не стало :-) что такое _большая змейка_?

Comment: мне кажется стоит задать вопрос как то иначе, например Помогите улучшить текущую реализацию алгоритма

Comment: @Grundy Игра такая старая, но не в этом суть, задача по моему ясная, есть массив ссылок нужно определить что произошло зацикливание

Comment: @Grundy вам что-то мешает реализовать битовое поле на обычных целых с произвольным доступом к любому биту? :-) Вообще 100M+ элементов и JS это уже несколько не то, чем стоит заниматься. Но если все же - чего б не сделать битовые поля?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов так? http://javascript.ru/bitwise-operators

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, тогда отредактируйте заголовок, на отражающий суть вопроса

Comment: Я правильно понял, что нужно определить что генератор ПСЧ выдаёт числа из какого-то подмножества циклически?

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich да, на битовых операциях.

Comment: @sercxjo если речь о ГПСЧ, проще добыть сорцы, посмотреть реализацию и почитать что про нее пишут. Наверняка этот генератор уже описан. Или переписать на С для скорости и проверять уже там.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, применять сортировку тут нельзя. Слишком медленно.

Простое решение: запускаем два указателя с разной скоростью. Если есть цикл, тот, что быстрее, догонит тот, что медленнее:

http://jsfiddle.net/wwzqvze1/1/

```
function check(arr) {
  var p1 = 0, p2 = 0;
  while (arr[p1] != null && arr[p2] != null) {
    p1 = arr[p1];
    p2 = arr[p2] == null ? null : arr[arr[p2]];
    if (p1 == p2)
      return false;  // not correct
  }
  return true;  // correct
}

var a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0],
    a2 = [2, 3, 1, 4, null];

console.log("run:");
console.log(check(a1));
console.log(check(a2));
```